# Hive: getting 'unable to alter partition' error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to insert data into my partition table using insert statement but its getting error saying `unable to Alter partition`

The query that I used :

```
hive>  INSERT INTO TABLE sms_partition table PARTITION(userc,coding) SELECT headerguid,messageid,userid,tonumber,fromnumber,smssplits,udh,operator,circle,vf,msgp,smstext,userc,coding from chotadata16june;
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR:Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.hiveexception: unable to alter partition .For direct metastore db connections ,we dont support retries to  the client level.
```

Comment: check if you are trying to insert data out of  partition range..

Comment: there is an extra `table` keyword in insert statement.